# Is the amount of energy that can be stored in a single atom infinite?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, atoms, kinetic-theory

In classical thermodynamics, the general explanation of how thermal energy is stored in a mass of atom or molecules (such as a lump of copper) is that the atoms in the mass vibrate with *almost* constant mean position and velocity of increasing magnitude, but zero mean.

> If we consider a single isolate atom in space being injected with energy in a way that it does not deflect it's mean position or zero mean velocity, is it therefore theoretically possible to store an infinite amount of energy in the form of kinetic energy of a single atom? Is the theoretical maximum of temperature of a mass of atoms (or molecules) infinite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort of. There isn't a hard limit to how hot something can get. But beyond a certain point, it won't be a lump of copper any more.

If you heat copper, it will eventually melt. If you continue further, it will boil. Then the electrons would separate from the atoms, creating a plasma.

If you continue to extremes, the nuclei would come apart into protons and neutrons. Then the quarks inside the protons and neutrons would separate into a quark-gluon plasma.

Conditions like this only existed for a tiny fraction of a second after the big bang. But they did exist, and they left an imprint on the universe.

Comment: Of course for a single atom the hard limit is the swarchild limit. Where the atom would become a block hole.

Comment: I agree with @mmesser314 mostly,  but i feel the upper limit would be when all the subatomic particles are moving at c.

Comment: @abrn2195 subatomic particles can only asymptotically reach the speed of light, and only approach it in the limit of infinite kinetic energy.  So this is an infinite upper limit.